# Find closest match when comparing array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array of objects, `foo`, and each of these objects has a property, `bar`, which is an array.

```
foo[0].bar = [1]
foo[1].bar = [2]
foo[2].bar = [2,4,5]
foo[3].bar = [2,4,6]
foo[4].bar = [2,4,6,7]
foo[5].bar = [2,4,6,9]
foo[6].bar = [3]
```

I need a way to take a test array and do a particular "best match" search like so:

```
mySearch([2,4,6]);     // returns [foo[3], foo[4], foo[5]]
mySearch([2,4,6,7]);   // returns [foo[4]]
mySearch([2,4,6,8]);   // returns [foo[3]]
mySearch([3,2,1]);     // returns [foo[6]]
mySearch([4]);         // returns []
```

Essentially, I want the objects in `foo[]` which match as many exact numbers in the test array as possible. Ordering is important, but the lengths of the test array or the target objects are all variable.

I can probably figure this out using an ugly amount of for-next loops and if-thens, but I feel like there should be a better way of doing it. (If it's helpful, I can provide a constant, `maxLength`, which is equivalent to the length of the longest array in the collection.)

Thank you!

EDIT: sorry, I had variables in the desired results mixed up a bit from a previous edit.

EDIT 2: Sorry I'm having such a difficult time describing this. The situation I'm dealing with is like reading: given a string of characters `"HELLOWORL"` against a standard English dictionary, I want a function that finds the longest possible word that fits: `"HELLO"` (skipping `"HE"` and `"HELL"` which are also in the dictionary).

Comment: Are the bars always in chronological order?

Comment: What do you expect `mySearch([7,6,4,2]);` to return? Would it return `[]` or `[bar[4]]`?

Comment: Chipster, bars are not in order, but I could certainly do a sort in advance if necessary.

Comment: Alpha, `mySearch([7,6,4,2]);` should return `[]`. If there was a `foo[7].bar = [7,3,2,0]` or `foo[8].bar = [7,6,3,1]` those would match because at least one or more of the first array members would match.

Comment: Even with examples given it's still unclear what exactly "best match" means

Comment: Sorry, hindmost... I've been struggling to put it into accurate words. How about "return all `bar`s which match the most number of leftmost array members"?

Comment: Regarding your edit, Alpha, it would not return `[bar[4]]` because ordering in the array is important. I need `[7,6,4,2]` and `[2,4,6,7]` to be treated differently.

Comment: Chipster, if you're asking if the array members of each bar are in order, they are not; I see now how that looks implied. Numbers can also be repeated. So there can be [50,2,47,47,149,2].

Comment: @TobyRush Ah yes. That's what I was asking.

Comment: @TobyRush So best match basically equals `bar[0] == test[0] &&  bar[1] == test[1] etc...`?

Comment: @Chipster Yes...ish. It's `bar[1] == test[1] && ... && bar[x] == test[x]` for the highest possible value of `x`.

Comment: @TobyRush That is to say, where x = test.length?

Comment: @Chipster It doesn't have to be x = test.length. It's x = as close to test.length as possible and still return at least one match.

Comment: @TobyRush So test.length or bar.length, whichever is shorter?

Comment: @Chipster Yes!... I think. Sorry this is so hard to describe! You can think of it as words: like how "for" would match "for", "forgive", and "forget" but not "fog".

Comment: @TobyRush Ah. No problem. Now I understand. Answer coming shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare same length slices of your `foo` arrays with the input array using `JSON.stringify` (assuming your array values are simple like the integers in your example). Then you need to iterate over the appropriate subsets of `foo` based on your rules for when to match exact length, longer and shorter length arrays.

See snippet below:

```js
const matchBars = (objs, arr) => {
  const matches = objs.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const len = arr.length <= obj.bar.length ? arr.length : obj.bar.length;
    const a = JSON.stringify(arr.slice(0, len));
    const b = JSON.stringify(obj.bar.slice(0, len));
    if (a === b) {
      if (len < arr.length) {
        acc.short.push(obj);
      } else {
        acc.long.push(obj);
      }
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, {long: [], short: []});
  
  if (!matches.long.length) {
    return matches.short.sort((a, b) => b.bar.length - a.bar.length).slice(0, 1);
  }
  
  return matches.long;
};

const foo = [{bar: [1]}, {bar: [2]}, {bar: [2,4,5]}, {bar: [2,4,6]}, {bar: [2,4,6,7]}, {bar: [2,4,6,9]}, {bar: [3]}];
console.log(matchBars(foo, [2, 4, 6]));
// [{bar: [2,4,6]}, {bar: [2,4,6,7]}, {bar: [2,4,6,9]}]
console.log(matchBars(foo, [2, 4, 6, 8]));
// [{bar: [2,4,6]}]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close... but I need `matchBars(foo, [2,4,6,8])` to return `[{bar: [2,4,6]}]` because the first three values match.

Comment: I've edited the original post with a little more clarifying info. Sorry to be confusing!

Comment: @TobyRush - what if you have `[{bar: [8,6]}, {bar: [8,6,4,2]}]` and you search for `[8,6,4]`... do you want to return both the shorter and longer match or is there some sort of preference rule for longer matches in a situation like this? In other words, only return a shorter match if there is not an exact or longer match?

Comment: Very good question... that helps me refine what I'm looking for. Plugging it into the larger situation I'm dealing with, I realize that my test array is always going to be as long as the longest `bar` array. So in this situation I would either be searching for `[8,6,4,2]` (which would match `bar[1]`) or `[8,6,4,!2]` (which would match `bar[0]`).

Comment: @TobyRush - ok, latest edit returns exact or longer matches unless there are none and then it returns the longest shorter match. That way it still makes sense in the context of your question since there is no clarification that the input array will always be as long as the longest `bar` array.

Comment: Eureka! This is exactly what I need! All due respect to Chipster, but I'm going to change this to the accepted answer since filters out the shorter and less correct matches as I need it to. Thank you so much!

Comment: @TobyRush No problem. Glad I could help, and glad you found something better.

Comment: @Chipster between the two of you I've not only gotten my immediate problem solved but I've also learned some new JS. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a try, not sure this is what you are after though.

```js
const foo = [{bar: [1]}, {bar: [2]}, {bar: [2,4,5]}, {bar: [2,4,6]}, {bar: [2,4,6,7]}, {bar: [2,4,6,9]}, {bar: [3]}];


    function search(arr, minLengthMatch){
       if (!minLengthMatch) // specify min match or use the default the arr length
            minLengthMatch = arr.length;
     return foo.filter(function(x){
            var matchFound = 0;
            for(var i in arr){
              if (x.bar.indexOf(arr[i]) == i)
                   matchFound++;
              else break; // tha match seq have been broken
            }
            return matchFound>=minLengthMatch
       });
       // change from .map to flatMap if you want a single array
    }

    console.log(search([2,4,6]));
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close too, but like with the solution @benvc provided, I need `search([2,4,6,8])` to return `[{bar: [2,4,6]}]` since the first three items match.

Comment: I've edited the original post with a little more clarifying info. Sorry to be confusing!

Comment: np but removing but `.map(x=> x.bar); ` would have got you the result you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a very simple way to do this, but for all I can see this would do the trick

```js
const foo = [{bar: [1]}, {bar: [2]}, {bar: [2,4,5]}, {bar: [2,4,6]}, {bar: [2,4,6,7]}, {bar: [2,4,6,9]}, {bar: [3]}, {bar: [3, 4]}];

const mySearch = searchArray => {
  var maxMatch = 0;
  const searchString = searchArray.join("")
  const matchingObjectsArray =  foo.map(obj => {
    const barString = obj.bar.join("")         
    if (barString.startsWith(searchString) 
       || searchString.startsWith(barString)){
       
        maxMatch = searchString.length >= barString.length ?
                    barString.length : 
                    searchString.length

       return obj
     }else return null //if there are no matches replace obj with null
   }).filter(Boolean) // get rid of nulls
  const filteredMatches = matchingObjectsArray
                          .filter(obj => obj.bar.length >= maxMatch)
                              
  return filteredMatches
}
console.log(mySearch([3,4,6,9])) /* { bar: [ 3, 4 ] } ] */
```

Comment: Ah, my fault for not being clearer. I can see where this solution would be useful in other situations, but for this situation the leftmost items have to match. So `mySearch([3,4,6,9])` should just return `{bar: [3]}`.

Comment: I've edited the original post with a little more clarifying info. Sorry to be confusing!

Comment: I think i understand now =). Basically you want one of the arrays to start same as the other, with as much length matching?

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** An earlier version of this answer had a misuse of foreach in Javascript. This answer has been edited to fix that

I think I got you now.

Here is a solution that has only 2 loops and 2 ifs:

> **NOTE:** This solution assumes foo is a global var. It might be a good idea to pass foo, or make `mySearch()` a member function of foo instead, but hopefully this is enough to give you the picture.

```
mySearch(test) {
    var result[]; // the list of matches
    var maxLen = 0; // to be filled later
    // loop control vars.
    var j=0;
    var i=0;
    // loop 1, for searching every bar
    for(j=0;j<foo.length;j++) {
        // if 1, for knowing our max length. 
        // Could be replaced with a ?:, but I don't remember if those exist in js
        // if they do, it'd look something like
        // maxLen = foo[j].bar.length > test.length ? test.length : foo[j].bar.length;
        if(foo[j].bar.length > test.length) {
            maxLen = test.length;
        } else {
            maxLen = foo[j].bar.length;
        }

        // a flag to hold if our current bar matches
        var doesMatch = true;

        // loop 2. This one is because we have a variable amount of
        for(i =0; i<maxLen;i++) {
            doesMatch = doesMatch && (foo[j].bar[i] == test[i]); 
        }

        // if 2, see what we matched
        if(doesMatch) {
            // if we did, add it to the results
            result.push(foo[j]);
        }
    }
    // return what matched
    return result;
}
```

Hopefully this is efficient enough for what you're looking for.

P.S. with the ?: syntax you could change the line `maxLen = myFoo.bar.length > test.length ? test.length : foo[j].bar.length;` to **`var`**`maxLen = foo[j].bar.length > test.length ? test.length : foo[j].bar.length;` since maxLen is only used in the loop.

P.P.S. You also mentioned that you already have a `maxLength` available, so if it serves the same purpose as my `maxLen` then you could use that instead.

Comment: Ooh... I think this might do the trick. `mySearch([2,4,6,7])` is returning `[{bar: [2]}, {bar: [2, 4, 6]}, {bar: [2, 4, 6, 7]}]`, instead of just `[{bar: [2, 4, 6, 7]}]`, but I can easily fix that by taking the longest returned array. Marking this solved, but I might be pestering you after I plug it into my larger project tomorrow morning if you don't mind :)

Comment: Well, SE and SO don't like extended conversations, but if you have something related to this question or answer you can certainly add it, or you can start another question or a chat and invite me if you have a question about something not related to this question and think I can help.